# SMPS Grounding and Earthing

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, grounding, emi-filtering

I'm trying to design the isolated SMPS circuit. I'm a newbie on power electronics and I'm using a circuit design tool to design SMPS. I have confusion about grounding and earthing. My system will have a PE(Protective Earth) connection but I'm not clear to where I must connect it?

The auto-created circuit designed by the tool is below.
As schema shows that Y1/Y2 safety capacitor is connected through the rectifier ground (I called it Primary Ground)
[image]

I got and SMPS and investigated the circuit. They connected safety capacitors to PE not to Primary Ground. And they made connection between all grounds and PE by other safety capacitors.
[image]

Which way to I use?
As I guess the auto-created circuit for Class 2 applications. My design will be Class 1 (PE connected) so I must design something like the second one. I need expert advice about this grounding issue.

Comment: The capacitors are there for reasons of EMI suppression and that EMI will be heavily influenced by your design.

Comment: I agreed. But I'm not clear about connecting them to either PE or Primary Ground. (the section that before rectifier circuit) Doesn't it change anything?

Comment: What you call primary ground is not earth; it's just a reference node name and not real earth or PE. Don't confuse the two.

Comment: Primary Ground is a kind of Ground that used for Pwm controller, MOSFET, optocoupler, and negative side of the input bulk capacitor. A point that a  confused is I must or musn't connect Y1/Y2 safety  capacitor(Line to earth/ Neutral to earth) to PE or direct to the Primary Ground. Auto-created circuit says that I must connect it to primary ground but real smps circuit says that I must connect it to PE.

Comment: Then "auto-created-circuit" is wrong.

Comment: The LINE return (Neutral) will be tie to PE at some point in your building (distribution panel etc) thus you need to ensure you do not tie what you call your "primary ground" to either CHASSIS, Neutral etc.. Your unit should have a dedicated bonding point for Chassis for EMI reasons to tie to some metal work. This should be different from the PE as PE should have no current flowing through it. Key thing to remember is ... not all grounds are equal - in their potential, their impedance, their usage.  PE is something very specific, don't mix it

Comment: It looks like the "Auto-Created-Circuit" is created by TI's Webench Power Designer. I've just created a test circuit *(Universal Input, 12V/20A Isolated Output)* and it put the same ground symbol for PE, Pri-GND, and Sec-GND, which means they are all connected together. So, the GND connections are wrong in the "Auto-Created-Circuit", as Andy has already pointed out. The first thing you should know is that you shouldn't connect Pri-GND to PE as it'll cause a short-circuit.

Comment: The circuit you show isn't an SMPS, and it's not isolated.  But it might be the front end of one.

Comment: @RohatKılıç Yes, you are right! I agreed you the tool is wrong. I researched evaluation board schematic released from same company ıt connects Y1/Y2 to PE not primary ground. https://i.ibb.co/MfFBHWY/TRUECHEMA.png

Comment: @SimonB Yes it is the input side of SMPS I haven't shown all circuit.